# Link to discussion detail view or flat view gets broken if new subject view is created

Tags: 2013, view, discussion-board

Whenever I try to create new subject view of discussion board with different name, the link to flat view for discussion detail is broken, rather it opens the new subject view again. Has anyone else had this problem? And is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered a similar issue after editing the ReadOnly value of the Allitems.aspx view (Subject) to *ReadOnly="False"*. When I saved the file, it changed the *Show this view* value (on the *Edit View* page) to *In all folders*. Once I changed that back to *In the top-level folder*, discussions would default back to the flat view.